# How do native speakers say 'I have completed all the missions/levels in the game'?

Tags: word-usage, phrase-usage, idioms

I read on one forum you can say "**finish**" but that was it, there were no examples. So what I am looking for is how to ask someone if he or she has "gone through" all the missions, played every single level and completed the game.
Would this work?

> -Hey, Mike, ever played BioShock Infinite?
>
> -Yep. My fav actually.
>
> -Cool. Finished it all? (Have you finished it? Have you finished it all?)

And are there other ways to ask this, even if it's "gaming slang"?

These also sound good at least to me :) "Have you played it all?", "Have you played the whole game?". Can the word "**pass**" be used in this context?

Comment: Do you mean only completing the main storyline, or would you also include the side-quests and getting all the achievements?  "Beating the game" would be different from "100%ing the game".

Comment: Darthfett, I mean to play a game to a point where it's done, it's over, you have done everything possible, passed every level and saw the final "You Won" message.

Comment: It kind of looks like you are asking two questions here: How to ask someone else about game completion (body of your question) and how to respond (subject of your question). Also it's worth noting most people will complete a game well before they 100% it.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

"Beat the game" is probably the most popular way to say that you completed a game. However, it does not necessarily imply that you have completed "everything possible", like OP is asking. It's more likely to imply that you completed enough to see the "ending", which is especially misleading if the game has multiple endings, and even more misleading when there is only one true ending, per se.

It means that every level was completed if the game has to be played in a linear/sequential manner (eg if every level must be completed in order to progress complete the game).

To be explicit (which is what OP seems to want) that you completed every level or mission, you should include something, like

> I beat **every** level.

---

Actually, the example in your title seems a little formal, but fine nonetheless.

> 1. I have completed all the missions/levels in the game.

If you and the listener understand that you are talking about a game, then "in the game" seems redundant.

> 2. Finished it all?
> 3. Have you finished it?
> 4. Have you finished it all?

These all seem fine, but 2. sounds the most casual.

> 5. Have you played it all?
> 6. Have you played the whole game?

These questions sound fine, but they do not necessarily ask whether or not the listener has completed every level/mission. As you know, in some games, you can play the whole game, but not complete every single mission/level. (I cannot think of any at the moment.)

Some alternatives are "pass", "beat", "complete":

> 7. I beat/passed/completed every level/mission!
> 8. I beat/passed/completed all the levels/missions!
> 9. I beat/completed the whole game!
> 10. Have you beaten/passed/completed every level/mission?
> 11. Have you beaten/passed/completed all the levels/missions?
> 12. Have you beaten/completed the whole game?

I think "I passed the whole game" and "Have you passed the whole game?" might sound strange. This list is not meant to be exhaustive and I'm sure there's plenty of slang out there that will work.

Comment: As an alternative to "all the levels," one could ask, "Have you finished _every_ level?" (or maybe, "Have you made it through the final level?").

Comment: J.R., thanks. Will "have you made it through the game?" work?

Comment: Thanks, Max. Good to know you can also use "beat". Let's what others may add.

Comment: Another thing people sometimes say is: "I beat the game and the side missions." A "side mission" is something that you don't have to do in order to win the game but represents an accomplishment nonetheless. This is somewhat game dependent so you might say "quests" instead of missions, or "got all the stars" or "all the achievements".

Comment: I would not use "passed" in this context. Games are not exams, you aren't given a passing/failing score. I might say "Did you get past the secret door on level 13?" or "Did you get past level 400? That was tough".

Comment: @J.R. - these two questions are not necessarily equivalent. There are a lot of games that provide non-linear content in some fashion - this means that you can go to the final level and yet, you hadn't played every stage there is. It could even be that there is _no_ actual final level, as you can play levels in any order and to top it off, some would be optional. The two questions definitely have different implications - the first means "have you done everything", while the latter is "have you gone through the main content". Worth noting that not all games have "levels", either.

Comment: Open world RPG's are the best example of not doing everything yet "completing the game" is possible, simply because games like skyrim, the assassins creeds or Fallout games, and such have many side quests that are optional to complete the main story. "finished the story?" is one of the better ways to ask if they did those main missions. For Primarily multiplayer games like Call of duty, it also works. You dont ever Finish them, you just quit, so everyone will assume completion of the game questions are based on the story mode, which you can finish.

Comment: For certain games you can also say that you cleared a level.

Comment: @Vld - I realize not all games have levels, but, given the title of this question, I was assuming the context here was a game that _did_ have levels.

Comment: "Beaten the game" says to me "Finished the last level" whereas "Beaten every level in the game" seems more like "Finished **every** level _(including skippable/secret levels)_".  For a lot of games they're the same, but for a lot they're not.

Answer (score 30):

I'd say "I beat the game" or "I have beaten the game," though the second sounds too formal even. It conveys the idea that you've finished all the levels/missions and is short and succinct.

You could ask a friend, "Did you beat the game?"

Specifying specifically that you have beaten/passed/completed all the levels is a level of detail that feels like a bit too much to me for a casual setting.

Comment: Thanks, Zach. Does it really matter if it's a strategy game or just some shooter? Beat works either way (probably meaning "to win")?

Comment: For both strategy and shooter games, I think you'd stick to beat. Any game with a clear endpoint is beaten once that endpoint has been reached. Beat in this context does mean 'to win.' If you can't finish a game (some kind of MMORPG, maybe) then you can't really 'beat' it. You wouldn't really say you had 'beat' World of Warcraft.

Comment: For an MMORPG, you might say you "reached the level cap" and/or you are "working on the endgame content". It's a lot more complicated for those games, since there is no ending, but there are landmarks of progress.

Comment: You can beat a lot of games without getting 100% or getting all the achievements, finding all the secrets, etc.  I think that exactly what I'd say would depend on the individual game.

Comment: "I beat the game" is my wording.  The term is general and can mean as little as achieving an ending or as much as full 100% completion of the game.

Comment: 'Beat' is definitely the correct term for this.  It might not appear at first glance to make sense in all genre contexts under scrutiny nowadays, but it harkens back to a time where winning meant playing long enough to 'beat' the high score.  As time goes on we now instead run out of new content--and thus have 'beat' the game.

Comment: The only way to beat World of Warcraft is to quit. I've beaten World of Warcraft a number of times.

Comment: Yep, "beat" is the proper gamer word. The other upvoted answer has lots of good terms an English speaker might use but in the actual gaming community vernacular of the day, that third question would be "Did you beat it?"

Comment: @Shufflepants: You used to be able to "beat" WoW by clearing the current raid tier on hardmode, before the next tier came out.  e.g. my guild beat Garrosh 10H before the nerfs when they changed class mechanics pre-6.0.  However, with all the pet-battles and Timeless Isle rare-mob achievements, and challenge mode and proving grounds, and other stuff that Blizz kept adding, it started to feel like work, especially doing it on 10 alts.  I did finish WoW 5.3 having done gold challenge modes on 10 of 11 classes, and wave 30 proving grounds as tank/dps/healer.  I quit while levelling my main in WoD.

Comment: Of course, some people would say you haven't beat WoW unless you have every achievement.  This is more rare, and only a couple people have done that.  Even I managed to restrain myself from doing some of the stupidly grindy achievements.  But anyway, I'm happier geeking out on assembly language on stack overflow and earning those nerd points than I was geeking out on WoW and earning nerd points in the form of achievement points.  Optimizing raid strats was a lot of fun, but I don't really miss it.

Answer (score 16):

I have heard this:

> I one hundred percented [name-of-game]

another example:

> How many games have you one hundred percented?

(I'm not suggesting that this is the most common way of phrasing this.  However, it is a term that I have come across.)

Edit: Adding examples:

- [10 Video Games You’ll Never 100%](http://whatculture.com/gaming/10-video-games-youll-never-100) (subtitle: “There are some games you'll just never bother 100%'ing; here are ten offenders.”)
- [TwoGeeksTalking : I will never 100% complete Video Games again](http://tgtmedia.com/news/will-never-100-complete-video-games/) (currently the site is going very slow, so you might want to check out: [TwoGeeksTalking: I will never 100% complete Video Games again (archived by the Wayback Machine @ Archive.org)](https://web.archive.org/web/20150223051718/http://tgtmedia.com/news/will-never-100-complete-video-games/))

Comment: I don't know of anyone using "100%ed" ***ever***.

Comment: Upvotes don't mean they knew it too, but that this is a good answer (reasons: creative, nicely formatted, good explanation, etc.)

Comment: I actually don't even particularly like the phrase: at 5 syllables (+1 more for "-ed" or "-ing"), it feels cumbersome. However, having heard it multiple times, I admit that it seems to communicate the idea rather thoroughly. Experience 100% of what was the creators intended/designed for players, including completing every main mission, side quest, and achievements, playing as every character (or, if that's unreasonable, every character type).  So, I simply mentioned it because, in my opinion, it was a very applicable answer that could be added to the mix.

Comment: @ErikKonstantopoulos On the contrary, this is the phrase I use, although like TOOGAM, I find it rather unwieldy. It is the only one of the answers which specifically means "100% completion" as opposed to merely beating the canonical boss, which the OP has clarified in the comments.

Comment: Additional evidence: Speedruns imply that the game is completed, but they are split into ["any%" versus "100%"](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Speedrun#Completion) speedruns. Only the latter answers the OP's question.

Comment: I'd agree, this isn't an extremely common way of expressing it, but I have heard it enough times before. In fact, many games I've played even express the same concept *in game* itself.

Comment: +1 for the only phrase that communicates having done *everything*

Comment: Yeah "100%-ing/ed" is a thing. It's not used that often, but it's a thing. Usually comes from games that come with numerous achievements and/or games that do track your "progress" in-game - _Assassin's Creed_ titles tend to this, I believe, though far from the first or only example.

Answer (score 13):

Informally, people would often just say "Have you completed it?" e.g.

> -Hey, Mike, have you played BioShock Infinite?
>
> -Yes, it's my favorite game.
>
> -Have you completed it?

You might also hear someone say  "Did you play it all the way through?"

Answer (score 7):

There is one term used more by hardcore gamers, though you might find that unless the person you are speaking to plays games a fair bit, they may not quite understand what you mean

***"Have you clocked it?"***

"clocked" would usually refer to the deliberate action of beating all of the game *as quickly as possible*, but "clocked" can still be taken for "beating all of it".

You might also consider ***"Did you get to the end?"***, or in some cases, ***"Did you see the ending?"***, where you are actually referring to the ending clip that plays at the end of the game, to close the story. In the later, you are not really referring to having beat the game, but make the assumption that the person viewed the ending by playing the game all the way through to the end.

Comment: I have never heard this before.

Comment: I've been gaming strong since the late 80s and I've never once heard someone say this. I've heard "clocked" meaning "to punch" (ex. "Jim made me upset so I clocked him in the face), but only informally and only by my 78 year old grandfather (who is not a gamer). If someone said this to me in a gaming context, I'd ask for clarification.

Comment: @Scribblemacher, perhaps you are not the hardcore gamer you thought you were.

Comment: [citation needed], fersure. Definitely not in common gamer use, but I could see it being jargon of some subculture.

Comment: Maybe it's regional? Common enough for me in the 90s-00s in NZ.

Comment: @Blorgbeard works in AU as well.

Comment: @Timelord64, I think a more likely scenario is that my grandfather was a closet gamer. Now that I think back, I remember a time where we were doing some target practice and he shouted "NO SC0PE! PWND U N00B!" at a clay duck.

Comment: I've also been playing games as my primary hobby since the late 80s, and have never heard this phrasing in my life.

Comment: @DCShannon, maybe the terminology of the youth is lost on you.

Answer (score 6):

If you're asking, simply say something like "How far did you get in GAME?" as this lets the other person be as complete in their answer as they like and doesn't require you to know much about the game. Depending on the game you might want to tailor your question. "Have you unlocked all the alternate endings? Have you beat it on Hard Mode? Have you played through the game as CLASS/CHARACTER?"

Some typical responses might be

- "I got to part/boss X" if they haven't finished the game.
- "I beat the game" or "I beat the game on Hard" if they've finished the game or the difficulty level they finished on is important to them.
- "I got the Good ending and the Neutral but never finished the Evil run through." or something similar if the game has multiple endings based on your actions in the game.
- "I hundred percented it." if they did EVERYTHING.
- "I beat the game in TIME." if it's a game that is commonly speed-run.

It's worth noting that "finishing" a game can mean different things for different people and/or different games. Many games are meant to be played multiple times (high replay value) and often have different endings based on the morals of your character or other in game actions (sometimes arbitrary). And of course there are also plenty of multiplayer games where "finishing" isn't really an option... No one really completes Street Fighter for example. They might get all the characters and costumes unlocked but since the primary mode is multiplayer you can't ever decisively win.

Answer (score 4):

Those who complete every part of the game are known as **completionists**. Therefore, in gaming circles, to have **completed** a game typically means to have hundred-percented it (collected all achievements, collected all collectibles, levelled everything to max, etc). It does not typically imply fulfilling any personal, non-coded challenges, such as speedrunning it or whatever, so there may remain further gameplay over and above completing the game.

However, English being the evil thing that it is, this jargon gaming term will not give the necessary lack of ambiguity to differentiate it from merely **finishing** the game - that is, reaching the end of the storyline.

Given this, @TOOGAM's phrase "hundred percented" seems like the only phrase both unambiguous and in relatively common use.

Answer (score 4):

As a gamer I'd ask either:

> 1. "Have you finished it?"
> 2. "Did you finish it?"
> 3. "Have you completed it?"
> 4. "Did you complete it?

In cases where leveling is significant such as in an MMORPG:

> 1. "Have you reached max?"
> 2. "Did you reach max?"
> 3. "What level are you?"

Or in cases where your asking if they completed it along with all the achievements and the likes:

> 1. "Have you 100%'ed it?"
> 2. "Did you 100% it?"

Or if the game is particularly hard:

> 1. "Have you beaten it?"
> 2. "Did you beat it?"

In response to one of these I'd say one of: (using "Yeah" or some form of  affirmation when appropriate)

> 1. "Yeah I beat it"
> 2. "Yeah I finished it"
> 3. "Yeah I completed it"
> 4. "Yeah I 100%'ed it"
> 5. "Yeah I'm level [x]"
> 6. "Yeah I got to max"

Sometimes appending a time reference such as:

> 1. "Yeah I finished it last week"
> 2. "Yeah I finished it about a year ago"

Lots of people here are mentioning levels/missions, however a large number of games don't have them. Also, mentioning the name of the game at the end of the question is redundant if you're already talking about it.

Answer (score 3):

I'd say "have you completed every level/mission in the game?" is appropriate. Did you pass every level? is also fine. 
You could also try

> "Did you crack every level?"

I would only use 'finish' if I were talking about a book.

To ask whether they scored highest on every level:

> Did you max out all levels? / Did you ace them all?

In multiplayer games, the usual gaming slang is

> 'pwned it' or 'owned it'

Comment: Thanks, Sukanya, good answer. If you can use "pass" in "Did you pass every level" then can you also say "did you pass the game (all the/the whole) " ? Or it's just not the way ppl use it?

Comment: You're Welcome, Arman. 'Pass' can be used to indicate 'winning'. As in, "He passed all the tests". I wouldn't use it to ask whether the person 'attempted' every level in the game. The listener would be unclear whether you want to know if he attempted every level or if he got through all levels by getting the requisite score. "Did you try every level?" is a better way to put it.

Answer (score 1):

Not a native speaker, but I'd say

> [someone] has completed [game]

(without the extras)

or

> [someone] has beaten [game]

(with the extras).

Answer (score 1):

In my experience, when someone says they have *won*, *finished*, *beaten* or *completed* a video game, this means that they got to *at least one* of the possible endings that are considered "winning."  (Some games don't have a win condition at all, some only have one, and some have "good" and "bad" endings but neither can be considered "losing".)

You're asking about something a little different: what does someone say when they have done *everything* that is possible to do within a game?  Reached *all* the possible endings, found all the secrets, earned all the badges, etc.?  The term I know for this is *achieved [100% completion](http://tvtropes.org/pmwiki/pmwiki.php/Main/HundredPercentCompletion)*.  Some games give you an explicit way of tracking how much of "everything possible" you have done; the simplest version of that is a percentage on the save screen, and that's where the term comes from.

Answer (score 0):

In this kinds of chat we can use the simple word.

Did you play all the levels?

Did you complete all the levels?

I think it's much more easy to ask.:)

Comment: This should be "Did you play all the levels?" and "Did you complete all the levels?"

Answer (score -3):

Native speakers might use 'do/done' here rather than complete/completed (kinda formal).  Finish/finished is fine too.

"Levels" to me implies that you have to beat one level in order to play the next level.  So the key question is whether you are *done* the game -- i.e., you have advanced through all the levels.

Another dimension is whether this is recent/ongoing or further back in the past.

Levels/recent:

"Are you done the whole game?"

"Are you done all the levels?"

"Have you done all the levels?"

Levels/further back:

"Did you do all the levels?"

"Did you finish all the levels?"

"Missions" to me implies that you might be able to selectively choose which missions to complete, and the key question is whether you have done all the missions.

Missions/recent:

"Are you done all the missions?"

"Have you done all the missions?"

Missions/further back:

"Did you do all the missions?"

Comment: "Are you done all the ___" isn't really "good" English. "finished" works better than "done" but if you want to use "done" you'll need to add "with" or change the tense "Have you done all the missions?"

Comment: "Are you done \_\_\_" - I've been gaming for well over a decade at this point. During a lot of my time I've been in touch with the wider gaming community through the Internet. I've _never_ heard anybody use that phrase or variations.

Comment: OK, now that I think about it - "Are you done with the game?" is actually used. It doesn't imply _finishing_ the game, though, it's more about stopping playing it - regardless of whether it's completed or not. In fact, "I am done with the game" tends to be used if somebody stops playing before they've completed the game and somewhat regularly carries a negative meaning.

Comment: It's a good point that this is not 'good' English, but the original poster asked if there are 'other ways to ask this, even if it's "gaming slang"'.  I asked myself how I, as a native speaker, would ask someone this question, and I posted my phrasing because it was not already here.  I agree that asking 'are you done *with* X' implies you've stopped playing it entirely, not that you've completed it.  I personally would never say "are you done with your homework?" but I would ask "are you done your homework."

Comment: And 'have you done your homework' works too, so thanks for pointing out the 'Have you done X' variation.

Comment: I believe OP's intention is to get actual real-world ways of asking the question. As I mentioned, "Are you done the game" I've never actually encountered in usage at all.

Comment: "Are you done the game" definitely doesn't work. It sounds like something from Zero Wing... (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/All_your_base_are_belong_to_us).

"Are you done with the game" is OK grammatically, but As @Vld says, it would mean you don't want to play it anymore (e.g. you are bored of a game and are going to trade it in); not necessarily that you have 100% finished it.

Comment: Haha, this is fascinating. FYI - "are you done the game" is perfectly fine to the millions of native speakers living in these regions:  https://www.google.com/maps/d/viewer?hl=en_US&mid=1yZvlIxZsh97osqSbXcMPf9FvZaU But apparently we are not so numerous in voting on this page.